# Cache hierarchy in EHCache 2.10

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, caching, ehcache

Is it possible to define Cache hierarchy (abstract for example, or parent cache) in EHCache 2.10 ? I am looking for an XML tag like `cache-template` which is available in EHCache 3.0.

I tried this tag but I get an error that it is not supported.

Comment: Please expand what you mean by hierarchy and I do not get that tag reference.

Comment: tag name "cache-template" in EHCache 3.0 , Like abstract caches , or parent caches to hold the common properties of a set of caches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ehcache 2.x does not have the `cache-template` concept in XML. This was introduced in Ehcache 3.x. Note that you cannot have sub templates nor have a cache inheriting from multiple templates.

Ehcache 2.x has a concept of `defaultCache` but it is different and clearly does not allow definition of hierarchy.